# How to filter such array in PHP using one variable?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, filter

I'm trying to filter the array in PHP. Please see my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date_start_month_name] => January
            [approved] => Accepted: yes
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date_start_month_name] => March
            [approved] => Accepted: yes
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date_start_month_name] => March
            [approved] => Accepted: yes
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date_start_month_name] => April
            [approved] => Accepted: yes
        )
)
```

I want to filter the array using month name, for example: **March** and get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date_start_month_name] => March
            [approved] => Accepted: yes
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date_start_month_name] => March
            [approved] => Accepted: yes
        )
)
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance for any help. Best!

Comment: Is it me or you asked the same question a few minutes ago ?

Comment: So have you looked at array_filter()?

Comment: Duplicate of duplicate of duplicate... C'mon guys - if you can't answer why you still saying the same thing ?!?

Answer (score 2):

```
$march = array_filter($my_arr, function($value) { 
   return $value['date_start_month_name'] == "March"; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$array=array(array("month"=>"January","foo"=>"bar"),array("month"=>"January","foo"=>"bar"),array("month"=>"March","foo"=>"bar"),array("month"=>"March","foo"=>"bar"));
print_r($array);
$result=array_filter($array,function($o){return $o["month"]=="March";});
print_r($result);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => January
            [foo] => bar
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => January
            [foo] => bar
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => March
            [foo] => bar
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [month] => March
            [foo] => bar
        )

)
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => March
            [foo] => bar
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [month] => March
            [foo] => bar
        )

)
```